CPLEX and OPL: VRP variant solved with Branch-and-Price
I would like to solve a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) variant with Branch-and-Price using CPLEX and OPL. With the VRP variant, the number of vehicles should be minimized. Each customer must be visited and his demand be satisfied. Each vehicle has the same capacity to satisfy customer demand. Distances do not have to be taken into account.
I based my draft on the Cutting Stock Problem solved with Branch-and-Price from the model library. Unfortunately, the calculated solutions are not correct. However, I suspect that there is a problem with the dual variables. I would be very happy if someone could help me :-)
Best regards
Master model (flow control):
int n = ...; // number of customers
range J = 1..n;
int d[J] = ...; // demand of the customers
int c = ...; // capacity of each vehicle

tuple route {
  key int id;
  int visited[J];
}
{route} routes = ...;

float duals[J] = ...;

dvar int x[routes] in 0..1000000;
       
minimize sum(i in routes) x[i];
subject to {
   forall(j in J) 
   ctVisited: sum(i in routes) i.visited[j] * x[i] >= 1;
}

main {
   var status = 0;
   thisOplModel.generate();
   // initialize master
   var masterDef = thisOplModel.modelDefinition;
   var masterCplex = cplex;
   var masterData = thisOplModel.dataElements;
   // initialize sub
   var subSource = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
   var subDef = new IloOplModelDefinition(subSource);
   var subData = new IloOplDataElements();
   var subCplex = new IloCplex();
   var subObjective= -Infinity; 
   while (subObjective < 0) {
      // prepare master (relaxed)
      var masterOpl = new IloOplModel(masterDef, masterCplex);
      masterOpl.addDataSource(masterData);
      masterOpl.generate();
      masterOpl.convertAllIntVars();
      // solve master (relaxed)
      writeln("Solve relaxed master.");
      if (masterCplex.solve()) {
         writeln("OBJECTIVE: ", masterCplex.getObjValue());
      } 
      else {
         writeln("No solution.");
         masterOpl.end();
         break;
      }
      writeln("x[routes]: ", masterOpl.x);
      // transfer parameters and duals
      subData.n = masterOpl.n;
      subData.d = masterOpl.d;
      subData.c = masterOpl.c
      subData.duals = masterOpl.duals;
      for(var j in masterOpl.J) {
         subData.duals[j] = masterOpl.ctVisited[j].dual;
      }
      writeln("duals[customers]: ", subData.duals);
      // prepare sub
      var subOpl = new IloOplModel(subDef, subCplex);
      subOpl.addDataSource(subData);
      subOpl.generate();
      // solve sub
      writeln("Solve sub.");
      if (subCplex.solve()) {
         subObjective = subCplex.getObjValue();
         writeln("OBJECTIVE: ", subCplex.getObjValue());
      }
      else {
         writeln("No solution.");
         subOpl.end();
         masterOpl.end();
         break;
      }
      // check break
      if (subObjective > -1.0e-6) { 
         subOpl.end();
         masterOpl.end();
         break;
      }    
      // transfer route
         masterData.routes.add(masterData.routes.size, subOpl.y.solutionValue);
         writeln("routes: ", masterData.routes)
         subOpl.end();
         masterOpl.end();
      }
      // prepare master (integer)
      masterOpl = new IloOplModel(masterDef,masterCplex);
      masterOpl.addDataSource(masterData);
      masterOpl.generate();   
      // solve master (integer)
      writeln("Solve integer master.");  
      if (masterCplex.solve()) {
         writeln("OBJECTIVE: ", masterCplex.getObjValue());
         for(var i in masterData.routes) {
            if (masterOpl.x[i].solutionValue > 0) {
               writeln("route: ", i);
            }
         }
      }
      masterOpl.end();
      status;
}

Sub model:
int n = ...; // number of customers
range J = 1..n;
int d[J] = ...; // demand of the customers
int c = ...; // capacity of each vehicle

float duals[J] = ...;

dvar boolean y[J];

minimize 1 - sum(j in J) duals[j] * y[j];
subject to {
      ctVisited: sum(j in J) d[j] * y[j] <= c;
}

Input:
n = 6; // number of customers
d = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]; // demand of the customers
c = 3; // capacity of each vehicle

routes = {
< 0, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]>,
< 1, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]>,
< 2, [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]>,
< 3, [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]>,
< 4, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]>,
< 5, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]>,
};

duals = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0];

Output (not correct):
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 6
x[routes]:  [1 1 1 1 1 1]
duals[customers]:  [1 1 1 1 1 1]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -2
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 4
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
duals[customers]:  [1 0 0 1 1 1]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -2
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 3
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
duals[customers]:  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -2
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 3
x[routes]:  [0 0 0.5 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
duals[customers]:  [0 0 1 0 1 1]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -2
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
duals[customers]:  [1 0 0 0 0 1]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -1
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>
     <10 [1 0 0 0 0 1]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0]
duals[customers]:  [0 0 1 1 0 0]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -1
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>
     <10 [1 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <11 [0 0 1 1 0 0]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 0]
duals[customers]:  [0.5 0 0.5 0.5 0 0.5]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -0.5
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>
     <10 [1 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <11 [0 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <12 [1 0 1 1 0 0]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 0 0]
duals[customers]:  [0 1 0 0 1 0]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -1
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>
     <10 [1 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <11 [0 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <12 [1 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <13 [0 1 0 0 1 0]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0]
duals[customers]:  [0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -0.5
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>
     <10 [1 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <11 [0 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <12 [1 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <13 [0 1 0 0 1 0]>
     <14 [0 1 1 1 0 0]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0 0]
duals[customers]:  [0.5 0.5 0 0 0.5 0.5]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -0.5
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>
     <10 [1 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <11 [0 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <12 [1 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <13 [0 1 0 0 1 0]>
     <14 [0 1 1 1 0 0]>
     <15 [1 1 0 0 1 0]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0]
duals[customers]:  [0.5 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.5]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: -0.25
routes:  {<0 [1 0 0 0 0 0]> <1 [0 1 0 0 0 0]>
     <2 [0 0 1 0 0 0]>
     <3 [0 0 0 1 0 0]>
     <4 [0 0 0 0 1 0]>
     <5 [0 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
     <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
     <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>
     <9 [0 0 1 0 1 1]>
     <10 [1 0 0 0 0 1]>
     <11 [0 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <12 [1 0 1 1 0 0]>
     <13 [0 1 0 0 1 0]>
     <14 [0 1 1 1 0 0]>
     <15 [1 1 0 0 1 0]>
     <16 [1 1 0 0 0 1]>}
Solve relaxed master.
OBJECTIVE: 2
x[routes]:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
duals[customers]:  [0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333]
Solve sub.
OBJECTIVE: 0
Solve integer master.
OBJECTIVE: 3
route:  <6 [1 1 1 0 0 0]>
route:  <7 [1 0 0 1 1 0]>
route:  <8 [0 1 0 1 0 1]>


Do you need branch-and-price? If distances are not important, you're essentially solving a bin packing problem: minimise the number of bins (vehicles) such that all items (clients) with different sizes (demand) fit inside the bins. That's a relatively easy problem, as far as these problems go, and just a regular MIP might well be able to solve this.

Thank you for your suggestion. I want to use Branch-and-Price because I will be adding more constraints to this VRP variant. To simplify the problem, I have omitted them here. I would also like to know where I made a mistake in the implementation.
